# GET http://localhost[...] (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs, rest, http-get, resttemplate

I was trying to add a call to a particular service but this message keeps popping up.
I've tried using a simple http.get() call directly from js but it obviously ended up in a "same-origin policy" problem.
So I've decided to use a RestTemplate but the error is still there...
**This is the portion of js code:**

```
$scope.cercaClienteNomeCognome = function() {
    if (angular.uppercase($scope.nome) == undefined){
        var name = "";
    } else name = $scope.nome;
    if (angular.uppercase($scope.cognome) == undefined){
        var surname = "";
    } else surname = $scope.cognome;
    // OLD URL: ConfigPropertiesService.configProperties.urlricercaClienteNomeCognome+"cognome=%25"+surname+"%25&nome=%25"+name+"%25" 
    var url = ConfigPropertiesService.configProperties.completeURLItasServiziDocumentale + "servizi/getClienteNomeCognome?nomeCliente="+name+"&cognomeCliente="+surname;
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'partials/modals/tipiDocumentoExtra.html',
                controller: 'TreeController',
                size : 'lg',
                backdrop: 'static',
                //keyboard: false,
                resolve: {}
            });
        }

    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        toaster.pop({
            type    : "Error",
            title   : "Ouh nou!",
            body    : "[RECUPERO CLIENTI] Errore durante il ritrovamento dei clienti"
        });
    });
};
```

**This is the java controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getClienteNomeCognome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getClienteNomeCognome(@RequestParam("nomeCliente") String nomeCliente,
        @RequestParam("cognomeCliente") String cognomeCliente) {
    Object listaRisultati = null;
    try {
        listaRisultati = InterfacciamentoServiziService.getClienteNomeCognome(nomeCliente, cognomeCliente);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn(String.format("Errore inatteso sulla chiamata del servizio: [%s]", e.toString()));
        ;
    }
    LOGGER.info(String.format("Avvio ricerca cliente con nome: %s, cognome: %s)", nomeCliente, cognomeCliente));
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(listaRisultati, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**And this is the service called by the controller:**

```
public static Object getClienteNomeCognome(String nome, String cognome) throws Exception {
        try {
            final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            final String url = "someURL?cognome=%25"+cognome+"%25&nome=%25"+nome+"%25";
            final ResponseEntity<Object[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, Object[].class);
            if (response.getBody() != null && response.getBody().toString().contains("<error>")) {
                throw new Exception(String.format(
                        "La risposta del servizio contiene degli errori: %s",
                        response.getBody()));
            } else {
                LOGGER.debug("Fine chiamata al servizio di ricerca cliente");
                return response.getBody();
            }
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException hcee) {
            throw new Exception(String.format(
                    "Errore durante la chiamata. Error: %s",
                    hcee.getMessage()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(String.format(
                    "Errore generico durante la chiamata al servizio. Error: %s"
                            + e.getMessage()));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are Java controller and page with JS served from same host and port?

Comment: @MichalFoksa yes. The only thing that's not in the same host is the service that I'm trying to call...

Comment: What about the port of Java controller? If host is same and port is different then you still have "same-origin policy" problem.